# Insertion query get fired twice in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to `insert` form data into MySQL using PHP but somehow the `insert` query get fired *two times*.I have attached my code below...please help if anyone know about solution...

```
<?php
class Product{

// database connection and table name
private $conn;
private $table_name = "lspl_user_profile";

// object properties
public $id;
public $fname;
public $lname;
public $job;
public $dept;
public $email;
public $password;

public function __construct($db){
    $this->conn = $db;
}

public function create(){
    try{

        // insert query
        $query = "INSERT INTO lspl_user_profile
            SET fname=:fname, lname=:lname, job=:job, dept=:dept, email=:email, password=:password";

        // prepare query for execution
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        // sanitize
        $fname=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->fname));
        $lname=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->lname));
        $job=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->job));
        $dept=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->dept));
        $email=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->email));
        $password=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->password));



        // bind the parameters
        $stmt->bindParam(':fname', $fname);
        $stmt->bindParam(':lname', $lname);
        $stmt->bindParam(':job', $job);
        $stmt->bindParam(':dept', $dept);
        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
        $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password); 


        // Execute the query

       if(empty($fname) ||empty($lname) || empty($job) ||empty($dept) ||empty($email) || empty($password) )
       {
           return false;
       }
       else
       {
           $stmt->execute();
           mysqli_close($conn);
            return true;
       }
    }
    // show error if any
    catch(PDOException $exception){
        die('ERROR: ' . $exception->getMessage());
    }
}
}

?>
```

This is create_product.php file...

```
 <?php  
  if($_POST){

// include core configuration
include_once '../config/core.php';

// include database connection
include_once '../config/database.php';

// product object
include_once '../objects/product.php';

// class instance
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();
$product = new Product($db);

// set product property values
$product->fname = $_POST['fname'];
$product->lname = $_POST['lname'];
$product->job = $_POST['job'];
$product->dept = $_POST['dept'];
$product->email = $_POST['email'];
$product->password = $_POST['password'];

// create the product
echo $product->create() ? "true" : "false";
}   
?>
```

This method send parameters to create_product.php

```
 $.post("api/create_product.php", {
        fname: this.state.fname,
        lname: this.state.lname,
        job: this.state.job,
        dept: this.state.dept,
        email: this.state.email,
        password: this.state.password
        }
);
```

Comment: Please show how `Product::create()` is called.

Comment: From here, it looks OK. From somewhere else, create() is getting called one more time.

Comment: Use `mysqli_close($this->conn);` instead of `mysqli_close($conn);`;

Comment: how is create_product called? Is it an ajax request, or a postback? Might be worth showing how it gets triggered - possibly it's being called twice for some reason.

Comment: ok. is there any way that post method could be called multiple times? You should put some console.logs in your javascript (or watch the network tab) and logging in your php to see exactly where root cause of the extra DB call is. My money is on an extra call to the $.post method, there's no obvious evidence of any problems in the code you've shown so far.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, peoples..issue is resolved. Actually, I have made one silly mistake in HTML which causing post method invoke two time.

Especially, thanks to ADyson..